# Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $U \times (V/U)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I was reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, and the following question appears as exercise $12$ in chapter $3$, section $E$.

> Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $V/U$ is finite-dimensional.
>
> Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $U \times (V/U)$.

I solve it as follows:

Since $V/U$ is finite-dimensional then we can find a basis, let it be:
$$(v_1 + U) + \cdots + (v_n + U) \quad;\enspace v_i \in V ,\text{for } i = 1,..,n$$
It is clear that $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ are independent.

Now for any list of vectors in $V$ that have $\text{length} \geq n + 1$, we know that this list is dependent because otherwise, we can construct an independent list in $V/U$ with a length greater than the length of its basis which is impossible.

So it must be that $V$ is also finite-dimensional and since $U$ is a subspace of $V$ it must be finite-dimensional.

Now we can proceed easily as follows:
$$\dim U \times (V/U) = \dim U + \dim V/U = \dim U + \dim V - \dim U = \dim V$$
And since we know that:

> Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

We can conclude that $V$ is isomorphic to $U \times (V/U)$.

Is my solution correct?

Also please note that I know the other solutions to this problem so **I am not asking for other solutions**.

Comment: Is finite dimensionality part of the hypotheses? i.e., is there a "$\dim V$" in the first instance? Infinite dimensional vector spaces can have finite dimensional quotients.

Comment: This is false: "Now for any list of vectors in $V$ that have $length \geq n + 1$, we know that this list is dependent because otherwise, we can construct an independent list in $V/U$ with a length greater than the length of its basis which is impossible." If it were true then any infinite dimensional linear space would only have finite dimensional qutients, which is false.

Comment: to add to @DonAntonio's comment, the main point is that taking a quotient does *not* in general preserve linear independence; the image of a linearly independent subset of $V$ in $V\big/U$ will absolutely not be linearly independent in general. for an acute example, take $U=V$. then $V\big/U$ has dimension $0$ no matter what $V$ is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. It is *not* true that $V$ has to be finite dimensional. For instance, if $V=\Bbb R[x]$ and if $U=\{\text{polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(0)=0$}\}$, then $\dim(V/U)=1$, but $V$ is infinite-dimensional. It happens that if you have a set of more than $\dim(V/U)$ elements, they don't have to be linearly independent.

Comment: Does the wrong happen because I assume that: "It is clear that $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ are independent." ?

Comment: Yes: that's exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: No, I cannot. My bad. There is no problem with that assertion. The error lies in the *next* assertion, when you claim that “for any list of vectors in $V$ that have $\text{length} \geq n+1$, we know that this list is dependent”.

Comment: Why? if they are independent then maybe $(v_1 + U) + \cdots + (v_{n+1} + U)$ are dependent or what?

Comment: Of course. For instance, take $x+1$ and $x-1$ are linearly independent elements of $\Bbb R[x]$, but $(x+1)+\langle x\rangle$ and $(x-1)+\langle x\rangle$ are linearly dependent, since each one of them is minus the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is wrong, and here's an idea for you:

Let $\;U'\;$ be the complement of $\;U\;$ in V, meaning : if $\;B\;$ is a basis of $\;U\;$ , then we can complete it to a basis $\;B\cup S\;$ of all $\;V\;$ (we need AC for this here if the dimensions are not finite), so in fact $\;U'\,$= Span$\,S\;$   .

Clearly $\;U\cap U'=\{0\}\;$ and thus $\;V=U\oplus U' \;$ . This means there's a unique expression $\;v=u+u'\;,\;\;u\in U,\,\,u'\in U'\;$ , for all $\;v\in V\;$ .

Now define

$$\phi: V\to U\times V/U\;,\;\;\phi(v=u+u')=\left(u,\,u'+U\right)$$

By the first part this is well defined. Prove this is a linear map which is an isomorphism.

Question: where did you use that $\;\dim V/U<\infty\;$ ?

Comment: This is not correct either. In general $U' \cap U$ will not be $\{ 0 \}$, for example if $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U = \operatorname{Span}(e_1)$, then $U' = \mathbb{R}^2$. Instead you need to choose a direct sum complement of $U$ (this can be done, e.g., by choosing a basis for $U$, extending it to a basis for $V$, and then taking the vectors of that basis that are not in $U$ and taking their span). In general there will be many choices for this direct sum complement.

Comment: @NateGallup That's right, I just was trying to avoid to get directly (because indirectly there is not way out) into AC, but there's no option. I shall edit that. Thanks.

Comment: How can we talk about a basis of $U$ if we don't know it's finite dimensional?

Comment: @DonAntonio By AC, are your referring to Axiom of Choice? Also, within Axler's text, he makes no mention of infinite dimensional spaces having a basis, at least not up to this point of the exercise.

Comment: @PaulAsh Do you really think only finite dimensional linear spaces have basis ?? Didn't you read that AC part in the answer?

Comment: @PaulAsh ANY linear space has a basis. In fact this is equivalent to AC on ZF Theory.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're missing my point. Here are the definitions of finite-dimensional and basis in Axler's text:

Finite-dimensional: A vector space is called finite-dimensional if some list of vectors in it spans the space.

Basis: A basis of $V$ is a list of vectors in $V$ that is linearly independent and spans $V$.

So based on these definitions, a space which has no list of vectors that spans the space is not finite-dimensional (hence it's infinite-dimensional). And without a span, there's no basis.

Comment: @PaulAsh You're wrong. Again, ANY linear space has a basis. To "have a list" of vectors that..." etc. means that space can be spanned by a countable basis. But there are spaces with infinite non-countable dimension and thus infinite non-countable basis, like the reals over the rationals, say.